# Multiplication of an orthogonal matrix by its first column

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I am given a real orthogonal matrix Q (nxn), where the first column of Q is the vector **x** (nx1) where the 2-norm of **x** equals 1.

I am asked to prove that Q<sup>T</sup>**x** has first entry 1 and all the others zero:

Q<sup>T</sup>**x** =
 \begin{matrix}
        1  \\
        0  \\
        .  \\
        .  \\
        .  \\
        0  \\
 \end{matrix}

For (Q<sup>T</sup>**x**)<sub>1</sub> we have x<sub>1</sub><sup>2</sup>+x<sub>2</sub><sup>2</sup>+...+x<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>=(2-norm of **x**)<sup>2</sup> = 1<sup>2</sup>=1.

Then, (Q<sup>T</sup>**x**)<sub>2</sub> = **x**<sub>1</sub>Q<sub>1,2</sub>+**x**<sub>2</sub>Q<sub>2,2</sub>+...+**x**<sub>n</sub>Q<sub>n,2</sub> which should equal zero.

However I have no idea how to sure this entry and all the other entries are zero. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If $Q$ is an orthogonal Matrix then $Q^T*Q=E$
 ($E$ is the unity matrix).
This means if $x_i$,$x_j$ are column vectors. Then $x_i^T*x_j^=0$ for $i\neq j$ and $x_i^T*x_j^=1$ for $i=j$.
Therefore $Q^T*x =(x_1^T*x_1,x_2^T*x_1,...x_n^T*x_n)^T=(1,0,0,...)^T$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since $Q$ is an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix, then $Q^TQ$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Furthermore, if $A$ is any $k\times m$ matrix and $B$ is any $m\times n$ matrix, then letting $b_1,\dots,b_n$ be the columns of $B$ (from left to right), then $Ab_1,\dots,Ab_n$ are the columns of $AB$ (from left to right).